# why does it take two clicks of a button for custom event to fire?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls, event-handling

I have a custom event that is used to alert the main page that a button has been pressed on a usercontrol.

However it takes two clicks for the actions in the main page code behind to take effect.

Usercontrols are loaded inside an update panel

The user control includes the following

```
public static event EventHandler SignOut;
protected void profileSignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SignOut != null)
           SignOut(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

the main page contains the following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Views.Profile.SignOut += Profile_SignOut;
            LoadUserControl();
    }

private void Profile_SignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuButtons.Visible = true;
        LastLoadedControl = null;
        LoadUserControl();
    }
```

and just for completeness, the load user control sections also in default.aspx

```
private string LastLoadedControl
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["LastLoaded"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["LastLoaded"] = value;
        }
    }

    private void LoadUserControl()
    {

        string controlPath = LastLoadedControl;
        ContentPlaceholder.Controls.Clear();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlPath))
        {
            UserControl uc = (UserControl)LoadControl(controlPath);
            ContentPlaceholder.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking for events is usually down to a PostBack issue, ie not catering for `if (!IsPostBack)` in the `Page_Load`.  I not 100% sure what's going on with yours because I haven't yet been required to dynamically load a user control.

But I can offer a slight alternative; if you're wanting to fire a specific event on the parent page from your user control, you can use this:

```
this.Page.GetType().InvokeMember("MyMethodsName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.Page, new object[] { });
```

Comment: That still takes two clicks, I don't mean double click, I can click once, wait like 10-20 seconds then, click again, then it works.

Comment: Actually, just realized the event was never working. On the second click of the button, the usercontrol that seem to exit/close.

Comment: You need to put in some breakpoints and see exactly what it's doing